# Check username availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form to user login:

```
<%= form_tag(@action, :method => "post", :name => 'signup' ,:onSubmit => 'return validate();') do %>    
  <%= label_tag(:user, "Username:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:user) %>
```

I want to check if there is the username in the database immediately after :user-field lost focus.  I can override this event on the form with javascript, but I can not send Ruby-AJAX request from javascipt code.

Is there any way to check username without adding additional controls (buttons, links) on the form?

Comment: without Ruby-AJAX request, how will you know whether the username is in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what reason can you not send an ajax request from javascript code?

The best way would be to send a GET ajax request when the focus is lost. The get request could then return true or false and your javascript could then reflect this on the page.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks.  I will think about it.  May be that is the answer.

Answer (score 37):

You can use some JavaScript (this one written with jQuery) for AJAX cheking:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-validate]').blur(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.get($this.data('validate'), {
            user: $this.val()
        }).success(function() {
            $this.removeClass('field_with_errors');
        }).error(function() {
            $this.addClass('field_with_errors');
        });
    });
});
```

This JavaScript will look for any fields with attribute `data-validate`. Then it assings `onBlur` event handler (focus lost in JavaScript world). On blur handler will send AJAX request to the URL specified in `data-validate` attribute and pass parameter `user` with input value.

Next modify your view to add attribute `data-validate` with validation URL:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:user, :'data-validate' => '/users/checkname') %>
```

Next add route:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'checkname'
  end
end
```

And last step create your validation:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def checkname
    if User.where('user = ?', params[:user]).count == 0
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => 409
    end
    return
  end

  #... other controller stuff
end
```

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, you should add the class `error` instead of `field_with_errors`. Also, it is a good idea to check with a username blacklist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful. I'm curious though - is there any drawback to using keyup instead of blur? I just implemented that on a rails app I'm working on and I like the immediate feedback the user gets (assuming there aren't any gotchas I'm not aware of).

Comment: I preffer `blur` event because of smaller server traffic. But if you should do `on-type` checking, than I don't see something bad with `keyup`.

Comment: To avoid multiple unnecessary ajax requests when using keyup, consider using a `throttle()` function like the one on `underscore.js`.

Comment: is this a complete steps to follow or should i do anything else beside this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another post.

It is a friendly way for validating forms if you do not want to write it all from scratch using an existing jquery plugin. Check it out and if you like it let me know!

[Check username availability using jquery and Ajax in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670868/check-username-availability-using-jquery-and-ajax-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that @Viacheslav has, works fine and my answer is a combination of his and my own changes *(especially JS)* part.

We will be using `Ajax` in order to achieve this.

Lets first create our function in the controller

```
def checkname
  if !User.find_by_display_name(params[:dn])
    render json: {status: 200}
  else
    render json: {status: 409}
  end
  return
end
```

and then adding our `routes` in `routes.rb`

```
resources :yourcontroller do
  collection do
    get 'checkname'
  end
end
```

Now lets gets our hand on the view. Below you'll see the input:

```
.field
  = f.text_field :display_name, onblur: "checkDisplayName.validate(this.value)"
  %p.error-name.disp-none username exists
```

And now by help of `JS`we get the magic rolling. Blow `JS` has few functions. `validate` does the actually validation. `getStatus` is our `Ajax` call to get the status and we use `showError` & `disableSubmitButton` to our form a bit more *production ready* to show errors and disabling the submit button.

```
var checkDisplayName = {
  validate: function(dn){
    checkDisplayName.getStatus(dn).then(function(result) {
      if (!!result){
        if (result.status != 200){
          checkDisplayName.disableSubmitButton(true);
          checkDisplayName.showError();
        } else{
          checkDisplayName.disableSubmitButton(false);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  },
  getStatus: async (dn) => {
    const data = await fetch("/pages/checkname?dn=" + dn)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        return json;
      })
      .catch(e => {
          return false
      });
    
    return data;
  },
  showError: function() {
    let errEl = document.getElementsByClassName('error-name')[0];
    if (!!errEl) {
      errEl.classList.remove("disp-none");
      window.setTimeout(function() { errEl.classList.add("disp-none"); },3500);
    }
  },
  disableSubmitButton: function(status){
    let button = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
    button.disabled = status;
  }
};
```