# Rails 4 Devise - Check if username or email exist before submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I am currently taking some time to study Devise with Rails 4 for a future app I am planning to create. I have successfully managed to allow users to access to the application via their username or their email.

Now, I would like to inform users whether the username they've picked has already picked up by an other existing user during the signup process and before the user hit the submit button. Github homepage has a three input field form that illustrates my aim.

For that I added to app/models/User.rb the following code

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
```

But this seems to not be sufficient as it only informs the user once the form has been submitted. I imagine that I could try to do this via JS but I am wondering whether there is Ruby only way to achieving this.

Disclaimer: I am fairly intermediate to Rails and a total beginner to Devise.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you need to use ajax.. it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670868/check-username-availability-using-jquery-and-ajax-in-rails

Comment: Thanks for your comment and that useful link

Answer (score 0):

There is no ruby only way to do this, you have to use javascript (ajax) to do it, and Rails give you tools to distribute the js to the page and communicate with it.

You have to remember that all the ruby code is executed on the server. The browser only work with the rendered HTML/Css and javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I have some experience with ParsleyJS and I discovered there is a also a Gem; do you think I will be able to achieve the interaction I am intending to?