# Accessing form values using javascript in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an input box, on the client-side, I want to access the value of this input box and check if it exists as a record in a model. If so, I want the data to be shown. However, I want this to be done without clicking a submit button/reloading the page.

Can someone show me some sample code?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815687/check-username-availability

Answer (score 0):

Sample code is very much frowned upon in these parts, I can give you an outline of what you could do. Use jquery to get the value of the input box, and submit this using an ajax request to some url. Map that url to a controller action that checks to see if that record exists in the db, and return some json that indicates whether it does or not. Then in your javascript, when the data is returned, you can display that to the user.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial on how to do this? I don't have much experience with Ajax.

Comment: Not sure, a quick google search shows up a few options, but I don't know how good they are. Check out the jQuery documentation, in particular the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method. (this should fit your needs)

Comment: I still very confused how this would work. I know you would pass along data to some controller, does that mean you can pass back values from the controller to the page as well?