# Checking username uniqueness during registration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I want to have a form validation during registration first i want to make a check if the `user_name` is used before or not and i want to make it from scratch without using gems in order to learn how it works, so I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815687/check-username-availability) and I am trying to implement an answer which i found it there
 1- I changed the js code to coffe using [js2coffee](http://www.js2coffee.org) in order to use it inside users.js.coffee not inside application.js

```
jQuery ->
  $("[data-validate]").blur ->
    $this = $(this)
    $.get($this.data("validate"),
      user: $this.val()
    ).success(->
      $this.removeClass "field_with_errors"
    ).error ->
      $this.addClass "field_with_errors"
```

2- I have this inside my routes file

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users" }
  resources :users, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update] do |user|
    collection do
      get 'checkname'
    end
  end
```

3- Inside my users_controller

```
def checkname
    if User.where('user_name = ?', params[:user]).count == 0
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => 409
    end
    return
  end
```

4- My form new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="inputs">
      <%= f.input :user_name, input_html: { data-validate="/users/checkname" }%>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Accept", :class => "btn btn-inverse" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

The error i am getting ( because i don't know how to make data-validate attribute works if i removed `input_html: { data-validate="/users/checkname" }` the error is gone but i cant have a user_name validation )

```
SyntaxError at /users/new
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
```

Any help with this because I have searched alot and cannot find an updated example

Comment: why are you not using the built in validations?  Is there some kind of improvement/added use that you're getting from this?

Comment: i don't want to use the built in validations, also if i could this work from scratch i will be able to use it in another way like , you cant publish two events on the same time on one day (thats what i want to accomplish but i am testing on username first )

Comment: also what if i have a long form with more than 15 field ? built in validation will not be good for users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't see any reason not to use the [uniqueness validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_name, uniqueness: true
end
```

Also, don't use js2coffee - you'll get bad code, and you'll never learn how to use js or coffeescript that way.

About 'you cant publish two events on the same time on one day' - you **can** do that with the built in validations:

```
validates :event, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:day]}
```

Comment: But i need the validates to be live ( during filling forms before click submit button ) can this be possible ?

Comment: of course - there's an excellent gem explicitly for this [here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations), and a great [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) that explains how to use it.  If you don't want to use a gem (although I suggest you do for this) you could take a look at the code in the github repo.

Comment: okay and one more question ( in timetables  (such as in a school) one teacher cant have same time on the same day (ex: if he has a section today at 9:00 am he cannot be assigned in another section at the same time) can the built-in validation do this ? note: its not one model

Comment: yup.  read the documents in my answer - you'd have to make a scope for each thing you want to do, but you could also just make some custom validations - there's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) about this, also :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<div class="inputs">
   <%= f.input :user_name, input_html: { "data-validate" => "/users/checkname" }%>
 </div>
```

data-validate should either be a string or symbol. symbol will not work in your case because its hyphenated

Comment: okay +1 my error is passed now , why its not working ? when i type an exist user name its not telling me that user name is exist and the create is works normally like there is no validation

Comment: Is your ajax call being made? Can you see that in your log?Try testing your javascript in browser using firebug or similar tools

Comment: I have reloaded `http://localhost:3000/users/new` nothing about checkname in the server log , and thats from the html source 

`<input class="string optional" data-validate="/users/checkname" id="user_user_name" name="user[user_name]" size="50" type="text">`